# Problem in Fiction Novel Template

Tags: memoir, templates

I have a problem with the following code, which I took from [this site overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/fiction-novel/pjdthvgdtsfy). I added `\section{Section 1.1}` to line 154 and my problem is this: in the output, at the top of page 2 of mainmatter, for example, it says 01.1 instead of Section 1.1. Why?
And is it possible to change the chapter number, for example, from 01 Chapter to Chapter 1?

Thank You so much

```
% universal settings
\documentclass[smalldemyvopaper,11pt,twoside,onecolumn,openright,extrafontsizes]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[osf]{Alegreya,AlegreyaSans}

% PACKAGE DEFINITION
% typographical packages
\usepackage{microtype} % for micro-typographical adjustments
\usepackage{setspace} % for line spacing
\usepackage{lettrine} % for drop caps and awesome chapter beginnings
\usepackage{titlesec} % for manipulation of chapter titles

% for placeholder text
\usepackage{lipsum} % to generate Lorem Ipsum

% other
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{hologo}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
%\usepackage{showframe}

% PHYSICAL DOCUMENT SETUP
% media settings
\setstocksize{8.5in}{5.675in}
\settrimmedsize{8.5in}{5.5in}{*}
\setbinding{0.175in}
\setlrmarginsandblock{0.611in}{1.222in}{*}
\setulmarginsandblock{0.722in}{1.545in}{*}

% defining the title and the author
%\title{\LaTeX{} ePub Template}
%\title{\textsc{How I Started to Love {\fontfamily{cmr}\selectfont\LaTeX{}}}}
\title{My Two-line-long Title}
\author{The Author}
\newcommand{\ISBN}{0-000-00000-2}
\newcommand{\press}{My very own studio}

% custom second title page
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\halftitlepage{\begingroup % Misericords, T&H p 153
  \setlength\drop{0.1\textheight}
  \begin{center}
  \vspace*{\drop}
  \rule{\textwidth}{0in}\par
  {\Large\textsc\thetitle\par}
  \rule{\textwidth}{0in}\par
  \vfill
  \end{center}
\endgroup}
\makeatother

% custom title page
\thispagestyle{empty}
\makeatletter
\newlength\drop
\newcommand*\titleM{\begingroup % Misericords, T&H p 153
  \setlength\drop{0.15\textheight}
  \begin{center}
  \vspace*{\drop}
  \rule{\textwidth}{0in}\par
  {\HUGE\textsc\thetitle\par}
  \rule{\textwidth}{0in}\par
  {\Large\textit\theauthor\par}
  \vfill
  {\Large\scshape\press}
  \end{center}
\endgroup}
\makeatother

% chapter title manipulation
% padding with zero
\renewcommand*\thechapter{\ifnum\value{chapter}<10 0\fi\arabic{chapter}}
% chapter title display
\titleformat
{\chapter}
[display]
{\normalfont\scshape\huge}
{\HUGE\thechapter\centering}
{0pt}
{\vspace{18pt}\centering}[\vspace{42pt}]

% typographical settings for the body text
\setlength{\parskip}{0em}
\linespread{1.09}

% HEADER AND FOOTER MANIPULATION
  % for normal pages
  \nouppercaseheads
  \headsep = 0.16in
  \makepagestyle{mystyle} 
  \setlength{\headwidth}{\dimexpr\textwidth+\marginparsep+\marginparwidth\relax}
  \makerunningwidth{mystyle}{\headwidth}
  \makeevenhead{mystyle}{}{\textsf{\scriptsize\scshape\thetitle}}{}
  \makeoddhead{mystyle}{}{\textsf{\scriptsize\scshape\leftmark}}{}
  \makeevenfoot{mystyle}{}{\textsf{\scriptsize\thepage}}{}
  \makeoddfoot{mystyle}{}{\textsf{\scriptsize\thepage}}{}
  \makeatletter
  \makepsmarks{mystyle}{%
  \createmark{chapter}{left}{nonumber}{\@chapapp\ }{.\ }}
  \makeatother
  % for pages where chapters begin
  \makepagestyle{plain}
  \makerunningwidth{plain}{\headwidth}
  \makeevenfoot{plain}{}{}{}
  \makeoddfoot{plain}{}{}{}
  \pagestyle{mystyle}
% END HEADER AND FOOTER MANIPULATION

% table of contents customisation
\renewcommand\contentsname{\normalfont\scshape Contents}
\renewcommand\cftchapterfont{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftchapterpagefont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\printtoctitle}{\centering\Huge}

% layout check and fix
\checkandfixthelayout
\fixpdflayout

% BEGIN THE DOCUMENT
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
% the half title page
\halftitlepage
\cleardoublepage
% the title page
\titleM
\clearpage
% copyright page
\noindent{\small{This novel is entirely a work of fiction. The names, characters and incidents portrayed in it are the product of the author's imagination. Any resemblance to actual persons, living or dead, or events or localities is entirely coincidental.\par\vfill\noindent Paperback Edition\space\today\\ISBN\space\ISBN\\\copyright\space\theauthor. All rights reserved.\par\vfill\noindent\theauthor\space asserts the moral right to be identified as the author of this work. All rights reserved in all media. No part of this publication may be reproduced, stored in a retrieval system, or transmitted, in any form, or by any means, electronic, mechanical, photocopying, recording or otherwise, without the prior written permission of the author and/or the publisher.\par}}
\clearpage

% dedication
\begin{center}
\itshape{\noindent{Dedicated to my all {\fontfamily{cmr}\selectfont\LaTeX{}} users.}}
\end{center}

% begin front matter
\frontmatter
\pagestyle{mystyle}
% preface
\chapter*{Preface}
\lipsum[100-104]
% acknowledgements
\chapter*{Acknowledgements}
\lipsum[1-9]
% table of contents
\clearpage
\tableofcontents*

% begin main matter
\mainmatter
\chapter{Chapter One}
\section{Section 1.1}
\lipsum[1-20]
\chapter{Chapter Two}
\lipsum[21-40]
\chapter{Chapter Three}
\lipsum[41-60]
\chapter{Chapter Four}
\lipsum[61-80]
\chapter{Chapter Five}
\lipsum[81-100]
\chapter{Chapter Six}
\lipsum[101-120]

% begin back matter

\end{document}
% END THE DOCUMENT
```

Comment: You do know that the "*M*" in MWE stands for *minimal*, don't you? `:-)` BTW if you don't want leading zeroes in chapter numbers then you shouldn't redefine `\thechapter`...

Comment: why are you using `\indent` with a brace group? and why use `\indent` at all in a `center` it does nothing as indentation is zero anyway in such a setting.  `\noindent{Dedic...`

Comment: don't do `\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}` it just generates a warning that it shouldn't be used.

Comment: There is also a `novel` document class (in TeXlive, but not one of the standards). Just to avoid confusion among others who find this thread: The OP is using `memoir` document class, not `novel`.

Answer (score 3):

You get what you ask for:

```
% chapter title manipulation
% padding with zero
\renewcommand*\thechapter{\ifnum\value{chapter}<10 0\fi\arabic{chapter}}
```

If don't want that, then delete the line.

Answer (score 0):

The other answer already covers zero padding.

For the section title formatting: in LaTeX you are not supposed to (ever) add numbers manually to anything like titles or captions - the whole idea of LaTeX is that these are added, updated, referenced etc. automatically. So, instead of:

```
\section{Section 1.1}
```

you write

```
\section{Section}
```

Furthermore, you are *also* not supposed to write the category of something manually. Instead you should give meaningful names and have LaTeX add things like 'Section' or 'Figure' automatically. Or in case you don't want to add meaningful names then you should define commands that do not take an argument.

So, instead of writing

```
\section{Section}
```

you should write things like

```
\section{Introduction}
or
\section{The Dinner}
or
\section{Cheese-flavored chocolate}
```

which are then rendered like

> 1.1 Introduction
> 1.2 The Dinner
> 1.3 Cheese-flavored chocolate

or if you don't want titles then create a new command that looks something like

```
\secnotitle    % hypothetical non-existing command that you can define
some text      % to print "Section X"

some text
\secnotitle
```

to (hypothetically) render maybe something like

> Section 1.1
> some text
> some text
> Section 1.2

Maybe you are instead looking for some kind of combination, like

> Section 1.1: Introduction

This you can do with the `titlesec` package that is already loaded with your template. Additionally you can change the format of the page headers. Relevant code snippet with both modifications:

```
% chapter title manipulation
% padding with zero
%\renewcommand*\thechapter{\ifnum\value{chapter}<10 0\fi\arabic{chapter}}
% chapter title display
\titleformat
{\chapter}
[display]
{\normalfont\scshape\huge}
{\HUGE\thechapter\centering}
{0pt}
{\vspace{18pt}\centering}[\vspace{42pt}]

%%%%%% SET SECTION TITLE FORMAT HERE %%%%%%
\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{}{0em}{Section \thesection: }
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% typographical settings for the body text
\setlength{\parskip}{0em}
\linespread{1.09}

% HEADER AND FOOTER MANIPULATION
  % for normal pages
  \nouppercaseheads
  \headsep = 0.16in
  \makepagestyle{mystyle} 
  \setlength{\headwidth}{\dimexpr\textwidth+\marginparsep+\marginparwidth\relax}
  \makerunningwidth{mystyle}{\headwidth}
%%%%%% FORMAT OF PAGE HEADER HERE %%%%%%
  \makeevenhead{mystyle}{}{\textsf{\scriptsize\scshape \ifnum\value{section}>0 Section \thetitle\else\thechapter\fi}}{}
  \makeoddhead{mystyle}{}{\textsf{\scriptsize\scshape\leftmark}}{}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  \makeevenfoot{mystyle}{}{\textsf{\scriptsize\thepage}}{}
  \makeoddfoot{mystyle}{}{\textsf{\scriptsize\thepage}}{}
  \makeatletter
  \makepsmarks{mystyle}{%
  \createmark{chapter}{left}{nonumber}{\@chapapp\ }{.\ }}
  \makeatother
  % for pages where chapters begin
  \makepagestyle{plain}
  \makerunningwidth{plain}{\headwidth}
  \makeevenfoot{plain}{}{}{}
  \makeoddfoot{plain}{}{}{}
  \pagestyle{mystyle}
% END HEADER AND FOOTER MANIPULATION
```

The line

```
\makeevenhead{mystyle}{}{\textsf{\scriptsize\scshape \ifnum\value{section}>0 Section \thetitle\else\thechapter\fi}}{}
```

means: if there is currently a section (i.e., the section counter `\value{section}` is not zero) then we print "Section sec.num", otherwise we print only the chapter number.

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. How could I do to obtain 1.1 Introduction, for example? Thx again. I just tried to delete Section in your last code-line of your answer. But the output has not changed. Why?

Comment: Could you directly edit your answer, please? Thx again in advance.

Comment: @Puck formatting like "1.1 Introduction" is the default in LaTeX, if you want that then you should delete the `\titleformat` line that I added. If you want the section title in the header as well then you should delete the `\makeevenhead` line that I added in my answer and replace it with `\makeevenhead{mystyle}{}{\textsf{\scriptsize\scshape\rightmark}}{}`.